# NodeJS / Express 4 - Sqlite3 - Storing rowset into variable

Tags: node.js, express, sqlite

I'm trying to store the rowset from the query below into a variable so I can play it into the view and loop through it.

I'm getting results from the DB, and can console.log them in the *db.each* block, and I thought I could generate my JSON object below and then store it - but it's not setting it for some reason and *var data = ""* just returns an empty string.

I am a bit baffled as to why - does anyone know where I am going wrong please?

Thank you for taking the time to read.

```
var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();
var db      = require('../lib/db.js');

/* GET contacts listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

 var data = "";

 db.serialize(function() {
    var rowset = db.each("SELECT b.forename, b.surname FROM contacts a, contact_attributes b WHERE a.contact_id = b.contact_id", function(err, row) {

      data = ' { "'+row.contact_id+'" : [ { "forename" : "'+row.forename+'", "surname" : "'+row.surname+'" } ] } ';   

    });
  });

  res.render('contacts', { 
    title: "Contacts",
    active: "contacts",
    contacts: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Is this an sync db call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database query runs asynchronously, executing the callback function once the query returns.  Therefore, `res.render` is called after `data` gets set to empty string, but before it gets set to the result set.

Also, there is no need to `JSON.stringify` a string that you have already built as JSON.

The code executes as follows:

1. `var data = "";`
2. `db.serialize`
3. `var rowset = db.each`
4. `res.render`
5. DB query returns.
6. `db.each` callback function executes, which sets `data`  based on the result set.

Try this:

```
db.serialize(function() {
    var rowset = db.each("SELECT forename, surname FROM contacts a, contact_attributes b WHERE a.contact_id = b.contact_id", function(err, row) {

      var data = ' { "'+row.contact_id+'" : [ { "forename" : "'+row.forename+'", "surname" : "'+row.surname+'" } ] } ';   

      res.render('contacts', { 
        title: "Contacts",
        active: "contacts",
        contacts: data
      });
    });
  });
});
```

or, avoid the manual JSON stringification:

```
db.serialize(function() {
    var rowset = db.each("SELECT forename, surname FROM contacts a, contact_attributes b WHERE a.contact_id = b.contact_id", function(err, row) {

      var data = {};
      data[row.contact_id] = [
        {
          forename: row.forname,
          surname: row.surname
        }
      ];

      res.render('contacts', { 
        title: "Contacts",
        active: "contacts",
        contacts: data
      });
    });
  });
});
```